# Unity-and other DE-problems in 12.04

Tags: unity, gnome, kde4

So, I installed 12.04 64-bit.  I immediately had issues getting Picasa 3 sync with web albums to work due to issues with WINE IE6 and 64-bit.  I decided it wasn't worth it and decided to try out several DE's to determine what was best.

I finally decided nothing worked better than Unity for me and started *attempting* to uninstall KDE and Gnome Shell.  I used a prepared terminal command with a list of KDE applications to uninstall KDE.  It didn't uninstall everything, such as KDE Settings.  I then tried to uninstall Gnome Shell.  It's not only still in the list of log in options, but it's still there.  But when I try the command to remove it, it says it's not there.

Not only that, but now Unity 3D is borked.  I get the desktop, but the top panel is missing and the panel on the left is missing.  I've tried re-installing Unity, but it says it's already there.

I may end up installing 12.04 32-bit.  I currently have only 3 GB of RAM and since I'm considering a new laptop before the end of the year, I may only upgrade to 4 GB.  I do still have XFCE and Cinnamon installed if I need to uninstall/reinstall Unity.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is unity available as Login option as `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 0):

These are massive projects that ubuntu allows you to install through a package manager.  Some times errors happen, but one thing that can be solved is not using Windows applications for one which will always be a source of annoyance and extra work in my opinion.  I would go with something like shotwell which is the default for Ubuntu.

If you installed a bunch of desktop environments you will never have a clean system again.  You will need to reinstall.  I am sure you could eventually get everything cleaned up, but it would be a waste of your time.

I'm not going to tell you which DE to use because that is asking for a flame war, but Ubuntu works well with what ever DE you use, but usually switching back and forth breaks keyrings and other application settings.

Comment: Ah, well, I had a feeling I would have to do that.  The reason I wanted to install Picasa was to get access to the web albums.  I had planned to download the photos through the Picasa then manage them with Shotwell.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If that is the case then you can use http://ubuntu-install.blogspot.com/2011/05/download-picasda-webalbums-without.html this tutorial which basically recommends you to download a extension for firefox that will allow you to download all the pictures the extension is called "Download Them All"